# mysql update join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

For a pedigree site I am looking for a solution for the following: there are 2 tables, people and relations. People can have several relations, but have only one relation as their Parents. People have an integer pointing at the relation of their parents, and relations have two integers pointing at the people that form the relation.
In the calculation of who has the most children I need to calculate the amount of children in one relation first.

The MySQL I used is:

```
UPDATE relations r
INNER JOIN persons p
ON r.ID = p.Parents
SET Children = SUM(p)
GROUP BY p;
```

But that results in:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY p' at line 5

What's wrong?

Comment: This is pure gibberish from start to finish.

Comment: there are "Primary Keys" and "Foreign Keys". Not "integers pointing to".  Without a clear description of your table schema we can't help you. Is `relations` a join table? In other words, is `relations` simply 2 columns where the 1st might be the person table primary key for the parent and the 2nd a foreign key back into the person table indicating a child?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do an aggregation like that in a query.  You can do it in a subquery:

```
UPDATE relations r INNER JOIN
       (SELECT p.Parents, SUM(p.p) as sump -- Should this really be COUNT(*)?
        FROM persons p
        GROUP BY p.Parents
       ) p
       ON r.ID = p.Parents
    SET r.Children = sump;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly what I was looking for and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

One way of doing this is:

```
update interstream.relations r
set r.children = 
(
select SUM(id)
from interstream.persons
where r.ID = Parents
group by id
)
```